# How to get True and False count comparing two tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I Have below mentioned two tables:

Table1:

```
ID        Code
URT-112   AAB
URT-113   12F
URT-114   234
URT-115   [Null]
```

Table2:

```
Merchant_ID     Flag
URT-112         CDE
URT-113         11F
URT-114         234
URT-115         DEW
```

By utilizing above tables, and considering `Table2` as accurate, I would like to know how many entries are wrong in the `Table1`.

I am using amazon redshift.

Required output should look like below:

```
TRUE    FALSE     NULL
  1       2        1
```

Comment: Hi, Does the posted answer work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when

```
SELECT 
  SUM(case when  t2.Flag = t1.Code then 1 else 0 end) AS TRUE_CNT, 
  SUM(case when t1.Code is not null and t2.Flag <> t1.Code then 1 else 0 end) AS FALSE_CNT,  
  SUM(case when  t1.Code IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS  NULL_CNT
FROM Table2 AS t2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t2.Merchant_ID = t1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

- Do a `Left join` from Table2 to Table1 using `ID`.
- Use aggregation functions like [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), with conditional functions/operators like [`Ifnull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), [`IS NOT NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null).
- `Code` is a [keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C). You should avoid using it as a Table name, and use some other name instead. If you still need to use it, you will have to use backticks around it.

Try the following (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iBuDoR5n9Wb7mLiqCFMZTb/0)**):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(t1.`Code` IS NOT NULL, t2.Flag = t1.`Code`, 0)) AS `TRUE`, 
  SUM(IF(t1.`Code` IS NOT NULL, t2.Flag <> t1.`Code`, 0)) AS `FALSE`, 
  SUM(IF(t1.`Code` IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS `NULL`
FROM Table2 AS t2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.ID = t2.Merchant_ID
```

---

**Shortened Version ([DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iBuDoR5n9Wb7mLiqCFMZTb/1)):**

```
SELECT 
  SUM(t1.`Code` IS NOT NULL AND t2.Flag = t1.`Code`) AS `TRUE`, 
  SUM(t1.`Code` IS NOT NULL AND t2.Flag <> t1.`Code`) AS `FALSE`,  
  SUM(t1.`Code` IS NULL) AS `NULL`
FROM Table2 AS t2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.ID = t2.Merchant_ID;
```